# Possible to pass worksheet to ClosedXml opened in OpenXml

Tags: openxml-sdk, closedxml

I want to use ClosedXml for all my excel reports. However, one of them is an xlsm with some charts in it that doesn't open in ClosedXml.

Is there a way for me to open just a couple of sheets from the original file in ClosedXml? Alternatively, can I open it in OpenXml and then pass the worksheets to ClosedXml so that I can use the ClosedXml apis to populate data and then pass it back to OpenXml to save it?